# monacadでcordova-hot-code-pushプラグイン導入できますか。

Tags: monaca

monacaでcordova-hot-code-pushプラグイン導入できますか。
https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push

Answer (score 1):

サードパーティー製のプラグインを導入する場合は、たしかゴールド以上の有償プランでないといけなかったはずです。
個人にはなかなかきつい金額ですよね(；´Д｀)